# How to get the day after tomorrow in PHP using DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime, laravel

I have an Eloquent query that  currently looks like this:

```php
$rides = Ride::where('date', '>=', new \DateTime('today'))
  ->where('date', '<=', new \DateTime('tomorrow'))
  ->get();
```

Which works fine, my question is, how do I go about formatting it like so:

```
$rides = Ride::where('date', '>=', new \DateTime('tomorrow'))
  ->where('date', '<=', new \DateTime('tomorrow + one'))
  ->get();
```

Meaning I am trying to find the results whose dates are between tomorrow and *the day after tomorrow*. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to get the day after tomorrow you can use:

```
new \DateTime('tomorrow + 1day')
```

You can find more information in the manual page ['Relative time formats'](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: Good to see you're using `DateTime` :)

Comment: what's the difference between `new \Datetime('tomorrow + 1day');` and `new Datetime('tomorrow + 1day');` ? (both working for me!)

Comment: I'm using `new \DateTime` to express that `DateTime` is part of the global namespace. This is to prevent readers from problems that can arise if the code-snippet is used inside a namespace. It seems like you aren't using namespaces, that's why both versions will work..

Answer (score 4):

`new \DateTime('tomorrow + 1day')`

It's OK if you are not interested in hours and minutes.. It's gives you always midnigth but

`$dayAfterTomorrow = (new \DateTime())->add(new \DateInterval('P2D'));`

gives you exactly 2 days from now and hours and minutes are kept

Answer (score 2):

The day after tomorrow is two days from now, so this will work:-

```
$dayAfterTomorrow = (new \DateTime())->add(new \DateInterval('P2D'));
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/Supko)